Solving Systems of Non-Homogenous ODE that Have Problems with Linear Independence
I've been struggling to find the particular solution to the system of ODE's $\vec{x}'=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&-2\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{pmatrix}2e^{-t}\\3t\end{pmatrix}$ using the method of undetermined coefficients, I know the general solution of the corresponding homogenous equation to be $\vec{x}_h(t)=c_1\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}e^{-t}$ and as such there must be something I'm supposed to do with linear independence since the guess $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}e^{-t}+\vec{b}t+\vec{c}$ wouldn't work
I've Tried to use the guess $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}te^{-t}+\vec{b}t+\vec{c}$ but in a similar way this doesn't seem to be working either.
I guess I'm just more curious if I can even use undetermined coefficients to find the particular solution in this case, or am I forced to use Variation of Parameters

Have you tried $(at+b)\exp(-t) + (ct + d)$?

Yes that worked, thanks for the help @Moo and @AlexJones! does anyone know the intuition behind why we make the guess a solution of the format $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}te^{-t}+\vec{b}e^{-t}+\vec{c}t+\vec{d}$ It seems reminiscent of the repeated eigenvalues case for homogenous systems and I know the reasoning there had something to do with the Jordan Normal form of the Matrix A, just curious if there are any parallels there

The solution to the differential equation of the form $\dot{x}=Ax+bv$ with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0 $is given by
$$
x=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)}bvd\tau
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}$.
The homogeneous and particular solutions are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
x_h(t)&=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0\\
x_p(t)&=\int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)}bvd\tau\\
\end{align}
$$
Let us assume $t_0 \geq0$ and $v=1$.
Let matrix $A$ be:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\
1 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Skipping the computations, the characteristic polynomial is given by $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+4\lambda+3$, with the following eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1=-3 & v_1=(-1, 1)^T \\
\lambda_2=-1 & v_2=(1, 1)^T \\
\end{matrix}
$$
The homogeneous solution is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
x_h(t)&=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0\\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-3(t-t_0)} & 0\\
0 & e^{-(t-t_0)}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{01}\\
x_{02}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&
= -\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-3(t-t_0)} & 0\\
0 & e^{-(t-t_0)}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
-1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{01}\\
x_{02}\\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-e^{-3(t-t_0)} & e^{-(t-t_0)}\\
e^{-3(t-t_0)} & e^{-(t-t_0)}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{01}-x_{02}\\
-x_{01}-x_{02}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
(x_{01}-x_{02})\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}e^{-3(t-t_0)} 
-(x_{01}+x_{02})\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}e^{-(t-t_0)}
\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
The particular solution is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
x_p(t)&=\int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)}bvd\tau\\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^t
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-3(t-\tau)} & 0\\
0 & e^{-(t-\tau)}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2e^{-t}\\
3t\\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^t
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-3(t-\tau)} & 0\\
0 & e^{-(t-\tau)}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2e^{-t}-3t\\
-2e^{-t}-3t\\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^t
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2e^{-4t}e^{3\tau}-3te^{-3t}e^{3\tau}\\
-2e^{-2t}e^{\tau}-3te^{-t}e^{\tau}\\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^t
\begin{bmatrix}
-2e^{-4t}e^{3\tau}+3te^{-3t}e^{3\tau} -2e^{-2t}e^{\tau}-3te^{-t}e^{\tau} \\
2e^{-4t}e^{3\tau}-3te^{-3t}e^{3\tau} -2e^{-2t}e^{\tau}-3te^{-t}e^{\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
(-2e^{-4t}+3te^{-3t}) \int_{t_0}^t e^{3\tau} d \tau - (2e^{-2t}+3te^{-t}) \int_{t_0}^t e^{\tau}  d \tau \\
(2e^{-4t}-3te^{-3t}) \int_{t_0}^t e^{3\tau} d\tau -(2e^{-2t}+3te^{-t})\int_{t_0}^t e^{\tau} d\tau \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
& = -\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3}(-2e^{-4t}+3te^{-3t})(e^{3t} - e^{3t_0}) - (2e^{-2t}+3te^{-t})(e^{t} - e^{t_0}) \\
\frac{1}{3} (2e^{-4t}-3te^{-3t})(e^{3t} - e^{3t_0}) -(2e^{-2t}+3te^{-t})(e^{t} - e^{t_0}) \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}
$$
You may do your own computations to verify your answer. Hope this helps.

thats great and all, but my question was more related to undetermined coefficients and if we can even use it to solve the nonhomogenous system; and if so then why is it that we make the guess $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}te^{-t}+\vec{b}e^{-t}+\vec{c}t+\vec{d}$ instead of $\vec{x}_p=\vec{a}te^{-t}+\vec{c}t+\vec{d}$

This is because for the homogeneous solution, one of the solutions is represented by the basis ${e^{-t}}$. The forcing term $2e^{-t}$ also has the basis ${2e^{-t}}$, which is repetitive. It is similar to having repetitive roots. For your particular solution, you will have to try another solution, which is of the basis ${te^{-t}}$.
If you cannot guess a solution of undetermined coefficients, another way is to directly applying the Duhamel's integral, shown above.
